# How to find process name with the help of process handle in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

How to find process name with the help of process handle in c#....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an easy way, if you already got the handle, you can obtain all the processes

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

then compare your handle

```
IntPtr myHandle = ....    
foreach (Process process in processes)
                if (process.Handle = myHandle)
                    ....
```

and at last get the Name of the process

```
foreach (Process process in processes)
     if (process.Handle = myHandle)
     {
          string temp = process.ProcessName;
          ....
     }
```

You have the Process class defined inside the namespace

```
System.Diagnostics
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Forgot that you need to call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` first to get the pid from the handle. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx). And if you look the Pinvoke page [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowthreadprocessid.html) you can find a complete VB.Net sample.

```
Process.GetProcessById(id).ProcessName
```

In the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid.aspx) for details.

Comment: As a warning, I think the OP said process handle and not process ID. In win32 they're two different creatures.

Comment: @Reinderien: Think you wrote that comment just as I'd realised that I'd forgotten that.